# Copy OLDVALUE to new CELL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This may be a simple question but I'm having issues. My code does not work. I'm trying to copy the pre-edit value of C2, to A1 (Same Sheet)

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var wscopy = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
var wspaste = ss.getrange('Main!A1');
function onEdit(e){
  var OLDVALUE;
OLDVALUE = e.OldValue;
wspaste.setValue(OLDVALUE);
}
```

Am I missing something? Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script,

  - Please modify `getrange` of `var wspaste = ss.getrange('Main!A1');` to `getRange`.
  - Please modify `OldValue` of `OLDVALUE = e.OldValue;` to `oldValue`.
- I think that in your script, the event object can be used for retrieving `wspaste`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != "C2") return; // Added
  var wspaste = e.source.getRange('Main!A1');
  var OLDVALUE;
  OLDVALUE = e.oldValue;
  wspaste.setValue(OLDVALUE);
}
```

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: Hello, is it possible to only trigger the event if the edit is made on a specific cell? Cause I only want this to happen if the cell "C2" was edited. Right now it triggers every time I edit the sheet. Thank you!

Comment: @Kelvs Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 1st question was resolved. About your 2nd question of `is it possible to only trigger the event if the edit is made on a specific cell? Cause I only want this to happen if the cell "C2" was edited.`, I modified above script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Kelvs Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.